# Como inserir CSS declarado com Javascript depois de rolar a página

Tags: javascript, css

Bom, só queria fazer funcionar a função javascript:

```
var $document = $(document),
    $element = $('#minhaDiv'),
    className = '.teste-css';

$document.scroll(function() {
  if ($document.scrollTop() >= 5) {
$element.addClass(className);
  } else {
    $element.removeClass(className);
  }
});
```

Mas não funciona de forma alguma, e parece estar correto!

Usei:

```
<div id="minhaDiv" class=""><br><br><br>...<br><br><br><br><br><br><h1>Teste2</h1></div>
```

e no css

```
<style>
  .teste-css
{
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

e coloquei no final:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Mas não roda de forma alguma.

tentei também:

```
  className = '.teste-css'; //CLASS
  className = 'teste-css';  //TAG
  className = '#teste-css'; //ID
```

e por ai vai...rs

[image: scree]

Comment: porque suas variáveis estão com $ na frente do nome?

Comment: a declaração de variável no JS não tem? O.o

Comment: Retirei o " . " da classe na variável. Testei e funcionou aqui.

Comment: Talvez é navegador então... (firefox)

Comment: se vc der um console.log( $document.scrollTop() ) ele mostra ou não? Dentro do $document.scroll(function() {

Comment: no php tem, no js desconheço essa necessidade.(Posso estar equivocado). Eu uso $ para selecionar tags(elementos) html

Comment: assim?   var document = $(document),
    element = $('#minhaDiv'),
    className = 'teste-css';

Comment: @AndréVicente não mostra

Comment: Então o problema é que nem o scroll está identificando, não é o nome da classe. Da algum erro no console do navegador?

Comment: @AndréVicente Humm... dá erro sim : nenhum elemento encontrado e04b:1:1
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
 overlay.js:7333:5
TypeError: aRequestOrigin is null policy.js:94:5
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
 overlay.js:7333:5
TypeError: browserElement is null
 overlay.js:7615:3
TypeError: aRequestOrigin is null policy.js:94:5
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
 overlay.js:7333:5
TypeError: aRequestOrigin is null

Comment: Acredito que não esteja encontrando os elementos. Jogo tudo dentro do `$( document ).ready(function() {   //joga seu código jquery aqui    });`

Comment: ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Não rodou... `<script>
        
        
        $( document ).ready(function() { 
        
        var $document = $(document),
    element = $('#minhaDiv'),
    className = 'teste-css';
$document.scroll(function() {
  if ($document.scrollTop() >= 5) {
    // user scrolled 50 pixels or more;
    // do stuff
    $element.addClass(className);
  } else {
    $element.removeClass(className);
  }
}); 
            
        });
        
 
    </script>`

Comment: Dá um erro `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` e aponta para essa linha dizendo que está com erro `$(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: Dá uma olhada: https://jsfiddle.net/pmqnnjpm/

Comment: Rodou direitinho... mas então é complico no meu ".php"... vou testar sem outros codes da página...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de responder a pergunta, uma observação sobre o que foi dito nos comentários: Declarações de variáveis em Javascript não precisam do `$` na frente. Até onde sei, isso é uma forma que desenvolvedores adotaram para tornar mais fácil a leitura do código, distinguindo que aquela variável é um elemento do DOM. Da mesma forma que usam variáveis com nome em caixa alta como convenção para constantes em algumas linguagens.

```
// Você 'bate o olho' e sabe que '$foo' é algum elemento no documento.
$foo.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<p> olá </p>');
```

No seu caso, o problema é que você está executando um script que depende do jQuery, porém quando este é executado o JQuery ainda não foi carregado.

Outro problema é que você está inserindo o valor de `className` na função [**`addClass()`**](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/). O valor possui um `.` antes do nome da classe e isso não é necessário, o jQuery tentará adicionar uma classe com nome `..teste-css` e nunca funcionará. **`addClass`** já sabe que será inserida uma classe, logo não é necessário o ponto, somente o nome da classe ( `teste-css` ).

Seu código ficaria assim:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .teste-css {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Desça a página</p>
  <div id="minhaDiv" class="">
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <h1>Teste2</h1>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function(){
      
      var $document = $(document),
          $element  = $('#minhaDiv'),
          className = 'teste-css';
      
      $document.scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() >= 5)
          $element.addClass(className);
        else
          $element.removeClass(className);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Matou a resposta Renan! Nossa! Eu não sabia que a sequencia de implementação dependia uma da outra... nossa que coisa!rs mudei a ordem do JQUERY com a função e rodou... O.o  Você e todos os outros amigos! Muito obrigado!! Obrigado mesmo!!

Comment: Kara, obrigado, legal, já está marcada, muito obrigado!! sou novo aqui!! valeu!!